# Flutter - Firebase Analytics Dependency Error

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-analytics

I have been building an app, and I wanted analytics in that so I added `firebase_analytics: ^6.0.0` as a dependency. But whenever I try to run the app in debug mode, I get this error

```
1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > File 'com.android.builder.files.ZipCentralDirectory@479a9b01' was deleted, but previous version not found in cache

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > File 'com.android.builder.files.ZipCentralDirectory@3cbd23b5' was deleted, but previous version not found in cache

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

But if I remove it, it runs in debug mode without any problems.

So far, I ran `flutter clean` and then `flutter pub get`, and also tried Invalidating the cache and restarting, but neither of those worked.

Here's my `pubspec.yaml` excluding `firebase_analytics`

```
cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
firebase_core: ^0.5.0
firebase_auth: ^0.18.0+1
cloud_firestore: ^0.14.0+2
fluttertoast: ^7.1.1
intl_phone_number_input: ^0.5.1
```

Comment: Have you tried using `flutter clean` and then `flutter pub get` after adding the library, in your terminal?

Comment: @ShababbKarim Yes, I did. It's still the same.

Comment: Did you also do `File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart`?

Comment: @ShababbKarim I did that as well

Comment: That's weird because usually when I get this error I just invalidate cache and restart, then it usually works.

Comment: Here's another weird thing. I restarted my laptop, tried the same process. Same problem, then restarted and tried again. And for some odd reason, it's working. I would like to know why that problem is arising though.

Comment: Not sure, probably some android-studio issue. For me I don't need to restart the machine, just invalidate the cache and restart AS

Comment: Using Intellij, hope that isn't any issue. Thanks by the way!